# Limiting software installation to specific user(s)

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, installation, privileges

Is there a way to limit software installation to one particular user or to a specific set of users only? In some software installers, this is available as an option, but in most cases the software just gets installed on all user profiles. I'd like to know if there's a way to prevent that.

This will be for computers running Windows XP, Vista, and 7. If anybody can point me to a related SU topic or a link, it will be much appreciated :) (Been searching for something like this for *weeks* already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it may be a pointer in the right direction:

> > Is there a way to limit users to run only some of the 
> >     installed programs?
>
> Sure. When installing programs be sure the install path is not in the "all users\programs" folder. Instead be sure to place them only in your startup\program folder. To see what programs are already installed in the all users folder right click on the start button and then click "explore all users" This will open a tree view and you will see the all users\startup\programs and then you can click the + beside programs to open it's branch or simply click on it to open the programs in the right window. Now if you want to remove programs from here you can leave this open and then open another E"Explore all users" and find your name under the Documents and settings and then click the + beside your name and then the + beside start menu under your name and then you will see the programs folder. Now you can click on it to highlight it and if you reduce both windows you can now have the all users\programs and the *your name*\programs open side by side. Then simply drag and drop the program from the all users into your program folder and this will limit their access to it. To drag and drop you left click on a program in the all users\program folder and holding the button down drag it over to your program folder and release the button. This may work in some cases. In others you will have to uninstall the program and then reinstall it and when prompted where you want the program to be installed click the "browse" button and then browse to the *your name*\programs folder and install it there only. Good luck.

Source: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/97285-45-limiting-users-specific-programs

Comment: Looks like it's a combo of setting permissions and moving shortcuts from one Start menu to another. Thanks for the link.